# Tests not being picked up

Tags: gradle, sonarqube

I have tests that are not being picked up by sonarqube. I.e. test coverage is 0%.

My source code is located here:

`scoringservice/src/main/scala/com/org/scoringservice/dao/tieout/TieoutRunDao.scala`

and my test code is located here:

`scoringservice/src/test/scala/com/org/scoringservice/dao/tieout/TieoutRunDaoTest.scala`

I am using gradle. All my tests run locally.

Comment: This is just a random guess, but I had an Issue with test coverage 0% in sonarqube the other day. In my case I edited the argLine of the maven surefire plugin without adding the original argLine with `@{argLine}`

Comment: If my random guess doesn't help, you should probably add more details to your question. Are other tests picked up by sonarqube? How is sonarqube configured? etc.

Comment: First of all, add information how you generate the test coverage data, please. Configuration of the tool, where are stored reports, check if they are not empty etc.